# Einstein Summation - Why is this term zero?

Tags: vectors

I am trying to solve a problem in involving two solenoidal vector fields $\textbf{P}$ and $\textbf{Q}$ in 3D space.

At one point in the question there is a term of the form $\dfrac{\partial Q_k}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial P_k}{\partial x_i}$ where summation is implied over $i$ and $k$ and is my answer sheet says that this should be equal to zero.

Does anyone have an explanation as to why this should be?

Developing from the beginning:
Im trying to prove that
$$\int_S[\textbf{Q}\times(\nabla\times\textbf{P})-\textbf{P}\times(\nabla\times\textbf{Q})]\cdot d\textbf{A}=\int_V[\textbf{Q}\cdot\nabla^2\textbf{P}-\textbf{P}\cdot\nabla^2\textbf{Q}]dV$$ where Q and P are solenoidal.

My working is as follows:
$$\int_S[\textbf{Q}\times(\nabla\times\textbf{P})-\textbf{P}\times(\nabla\times\textbf{Q})]\cdot d\textbf{A}$$
$$=\int_S[\epsilon_{ijk}Q_j\epsilon_{kpq}\dfrac{\partial P_q}{\partial x_p}-\epsilon_{ijk}P_j\epsilon_{kpq}\dfrac{\partial Q_q}{\partial x_p}]dA_i$$
Then using divergence theorem
$$=\int_V\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\left[(\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq}-\delta_{iq}\delta_{jp})Q_j\dfrac{\partial P_q}{\partial x_p}-(\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq}-\delta_{iq}\delta_{jp})P_j\dfrac{\partial Q_q}{\partial x_p}\right]dV$$
$$=\int_V\left[\dfrac{\partial Q_q}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial P_q}{\partial x_i}+Q_q\dfrac{\partial^2 P_q}{\partial x_i^2}-\dfrac{\partial Q_p}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial P_i}{\partial x_p}-Q_p\dfrac{\partial^2 P_i}{\partial x_i \partial x_p}-\dfrac{\partial P_j}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial Q_q}{\partial x_i}-P_j\dfrac{\partial^2 Q_j}{\partial x_i^2}+\dfrac{\partial P_j}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial Q_i}{\partial x_j}+P_j\dfrac{\partial^2 Q_i}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\right]dV$$

Now using the fact that both $\nabla\cdot\textbf{P}=0$ and $\nabla\cdot\textbf{Q}=0$, we know that $Q_p\dfrac{\partial^2 P_q}{\partial x_i \partial x_p}=0$ and $P_j\dfrac{\partial^2 Q_i}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}=0$.

If we could say that the terms: $\dfrac{\partial Q_q}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial P_q}{\partial x_i}$, $\dfrac{\partial Q_p}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial P_i}{\partial x_p}$, $\dfrac{\partial P_j}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial Q_j}{\partial x_i}$, $\dfrac{\partial P_j}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial Q_i}{\partial x_j}$ are all $0$.

Then we are left with
$$=\int_V\left[Q_q\dfrac{\partial^2 P_q}{\partial x_i^2}-P_j\dfrac{\partial^2 Q_j}{\partial x_i^2}\right]dV=\int_V[\textbf{Q}\cdot\nabla^2\textbf{P}-\textbf{P}\cdot\nabla^2\textbf{Q}]dV$$

My question is essentially whys should these terms be zero?

Comment: Your notation has inconsistent indices. In particular, $\frac{\partial P_j}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial Q_q}{\partial x_i}$ is clearly wrong. If you fix that, you should find certain terms cancel in pairs by relabelling the indices.

Comment: That's it, thank you so much!